# facing problem in vue apexchart dynamic data set from api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, graph, apexcharts

I am try to create vue barchart & using apexChartData.
Here is my code

```
export default{
  components: {
    VueApexCharts
  },
  data () { 
    return { 
    barChart: {
    series: [{
    data: []    
    }],
    chartOptions: { 
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          horizontal: true
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      xaxis: {
         categories: [] 
      }
    }
  }
},
methods: {
    myFunction() {     
        this.$vs.loading();   
        axios.get("/api/auth/nameofapi").then(response => { 
        this.barChart.series[0].data = response.data[0]['data'];    
        this.barChart.chartOptions.xaxis.categories = response.data[1]['categories']; 
        this.$vs.loading.close();
        }).catch(error => { 
        this.$vs.loading.close()
        this.errorResponse(error);
        });   
    }
},
mounted () {
    this.myFunction();
}
}
```

My API Response payload like

```
[{"data":[4,1]},{"categories":["xyz","abc"]}]
```

After doing this bar chart is not loading, i am not sure where i am doing mistake, sorry for repeating this post if already exist but i just post what i am facing.

Any Help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect you'll want to call [updateSeries](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateSeries) (or [appendSeries](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#appendSeries)) and [updateOptions](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateOptions) to render the chart again once you've processed your API response.